# Get Camera position and orientation using DJI API for Windows SDK

Tags: dji-sdk

I have searched windows DJI SDK API, but could not find a method to retrieve camera position. I would like to get the camera's position and orientation for each photo. Is there any way to get this information using Windows DJI SDK?

Comment: Unless that information is placed into the image's metadata there's no way for you to recover it after the fact.

Comment: I mean how to get information from drone to save as image's metadata?

Comment: Presumably by using the [Onboard SDK](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/).

Comment: Mavick Enterprise Dual does not support Onboard SDK. Which is why I am specifically looking at Windows SDK

Comment: It's not clear what you are asking for here: Do you want to query camera position and orientation during a flight to place this information into an image's metadata? In that case you would have to run code on the device (which, presumably, requires the Onboard SDK). If, on the other hand, you wish to post-process images, you would have to somehow map the images' timestamps to the recorded flight history, and retrieve the required information (if available).

Comment: First case. I wanted to query the camera position and orientation during the flight. Well, I don't think retrieving this requires Onboard SDK, WinSDK is just fine. For instance: https://developer.dji.com/api-reference/windows-api/Components/GimbalHandler.html#gimbalhandler_getgimbalattitudeasync_inline, will provide attitude information of Gimbal. Is it same as camera's orientation? What is the frame convention? These are the questions I am looking answers for

Comment: That's some fairly sketchy documentation. At any rate it appears that you can connect a program written against the DJI Windows SDK to the device and get live data (even though it's not actually running on the device). There's a [Camera Application](https://developer.dji.com/document/868bd800-1fc0-4f9e-a420-b7524a088909) sample that explains how to record video (using FFMpeg).

Comment: Thank you I am already aware of that. I am interested to find camera or at least the drone pose (x,y, and z). Would it be possible to get this information using the API? We can get lat, and long of GPS coordinates, but how to get pose?